# How to convert string hex into bytes format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, hex, byte

The string is like "e52c886a88b6f421a9324ea175dc281478f03003499de6162ca72ddacf4b09e0", when I run the code, the output is not my expectation, like this.

```
hexstr = "e52c886a88b6f421a9324ea175dc281478f03003499de6162ca72ddacf4b09e0"
hexstr = bytes.fromhex(hexstr)
print(hexstr)
```

The output is

```
b'\xe5,\x88j\x88\xb6\xf4!\xa92N\xa1u\xdc(\x14x\xf00\x03I\x9d\xe6\x16,\xa7-\xda\xcfK\t\xe0'
```

My expected output should like b'\xe5\x2c\xc8\x86......

Comment: `b'\x2c' == b','` so your output *is* as expected

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.

Python tries to be helpful by *displaying* bytes that map to an ASCII character as that character. For example, `\x2c` maps to `,`.

```
>>> b',' == b'\x2c'
True
```